# Regex for substring between two known tags that might appear more than once

Tags: c#, regex

From a string like this

```
http://a.b.c.d:1521/myApp/unreachable.stream/manifest.f4m?DVR
```

how would I extract only the part between ".stream" and the first occurence of "/" before the ".stream" with a regex, e.g. "unreachable" in above example?

Comment: Any code that you have tried? What kind of error did you get?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by the "that might appear more than once" part of your title?

Comment: I meant the first known tag "/" which appears more than once. ".stream" will only occure once. Sorry for the unclearance.

Comment: But there is nothing between .stream and the first /in your example. It's still unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: unlimit, I've tried (?<=/)(.*)(?=.stream) which gives me anything between the very first / in the whole string and .stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example with regex:

```
var match = Regex.Match(myStr, @"/([^/]+)\.stream\b");
string extracted = match.Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(extracted); // "unreachable"
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I've dropped the leading "/" to end up with ([^/]+)\.stream\b and it now fits fine, very fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for regex:

```
string result = url.Split('/').Where(s => s.EndsWith(".stream"))
                     .Select(s => s.Substring(0, s.Length - 7 /*".stream".Length*/)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you must use regex:

```
string regex = "([^/]+?)\\.stream";
```

http://fiddle.re/cyy8d

Answer (score 1):

Well if your input is going to be URIs like that...

```
var uri = new Uri(@"http://a.b.c.d:1521/myApp/unreachable.stream/manifest.f4m?DVR");

var streamSegment = uri.Segments.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Contains(".stream")) ?? "";

var result = streamSegment.Split('.').First().Dump();
```

Comment: Hm thats a nice idea, but some Uris might have an additional segment

Comment: Alright, you accounted for additional segments :o) so I would consider this a solution (thumbs up), but would you know the adequat regex expression?

Comment: @peter Updated with better code - but please expand on what you mean - I'm not a mind reader!

Comment: @peter 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.' :)